# Past tense or not in a statement about a general idea

Tags: tenses

Sometimes, I come across with a problem like this: I don't know if I should use past tense or not in the sentence like below.

> Nine out of ten adults live a mentally health life. The one who doesn't **experienced/has experienced** traumas.
>
> Every men lives a mentally health life. If he doesn't, he **experienced/have experienced** traumas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Nine out of ten adults live a mentally health life. The one who doesn't experienced/has experienced traumas.
2) Every men lives a mentally health life. If he doesn't, he experienced/have experienced traumas.

Both of these are really clunky. I would write them as
1) Nine out of ten adults live a mentally healthy life. Those who are left have experienced trauma.
2) Most men live a mentally healthy life. If he doesn't, he experienced trauma.

Ideally that idea would better be portrayed by an entirely different sentence. Something with more gravitas. 
Most people live a normal life. Others experience traumas the rest can not imagine.

If it's for a more academic work:
While 9 out of 10 adults live normal lives, a good number still experience trauma.

These sentences are, of course, factually incorrect as nearly half of people experience some kind of mental distress. Hope this helped

Comment: Thank you for refining my expressions. By the way, are my original sentences correct despite being clunky?

Comment: The tenses don't match and the data is incorrect. 61% of men and 51% of women in the United States experience trauma. Your data of 9/10 is true only if you are referring to Americans who are in behavioral therapy

Comment: I mean the numbers are wrong, I know. I am just asking about the grammar aspect of it. Could I write the sentence (1) "Nine out of ten adults live a mentally health life. The one who are left experienced traumas," if I don't care it is clunky? Is the sentence's tense correct? Because I don't understand why you said the tenses don't match. Despite it is clunky, it is still correct, right?

Comment: "The one who are left" is incorrect. It's either "the oneS who are left" or "the one that IS left" Also, "mentally healthY life"           The tenses not being right refers to you using "does not", present tense, and then using experiencED, past tense. In both sentences. It should either be "The one who does not, experienceS trauma." or "The one who has not, has experiencED trauma." in the first sentence, and "If he does not, he HAS experienced trauma." No S on trauma in any of them.

Comment: Thank you for the very precise answer. One more question: can I use past tense of the word "experience" in your sentence, so it becomes  "Nine out of ten adults live a mentally healthy life. Those who are left experiencED trauma"? Or should I add a time adverb like: "Nine out of ten adults live a mentally healthy life. Those who are left experiencED trauma in the past" or change the wording like: Nine out of ten adults live a mentally healthy life. Those who are left experiencED childhood trauma" in order to make it make more sense?

Comment: The second one may be considered repetitive because of the adverb, and the third one would depend on if you're only talking about people with childhood trauma. That excludes veterans or domestic abuse victims or severe injury survivors. It all depends on what you're using the sentence for because all three are good

Comment: Thanks. It is very patient and nice of you to put up with this many questions from me. Your explanations have helped me gain progress a lot.

Comment: No problem! It took me years to figure this stuff out. English is a very confusing language, even to a native speaker!